# Is there a Siddur with Tagim (crowns)

Tags: prayer-book, aleph-bet-letters, baal-shem-tov

As per the teaching of the Besht I’ve been really meditating on the letters as I daven but I realized that the true shapes of letters as they are written in a Torah or mezuzah which includes the tagim or the chatoret of the Ches for example are not in any of the siddurim I’ve seen. Is there a siddur which includes the letters as they are written in a Torah?

Comment: I'm not sure what makes Taggim and such "truer" forms of the letter, but in any event what you're seeking may be prohibited https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%93_%D7%91

Comment: @DoubleAA Why are stam letters any more Ashurit than the way they're printed commonly in siddurim? (Of course, you could argue that the common siddur is also asur, but this hardly seems the place for that comment.)

Comment: @magicker they may not be less ashuri depending on the font, but they are less כתב אשורית שכותבין בו התורה

Comment: @DoubleAA it says "דברים של חול".

Answer (score 3):

Tagim can be usually found in siddurim printed in Ktav Ashurit. These are usually Kabbalistic (with kavanot haAri), Chassidic (Nusach Sefard, especially the Biala or Toldos Aharon versions) or Sepharadic (Nusach Edot Hamizrach - Sefaradi) siddurim. Here are some examples:

https://ashuris.org/product/siddur-weekday-sfard/

https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/siddur-chelkas-yehoshua-for-shabbos-large-size-S889592.html

https://seforimcenter.com/Siddur-Shiviti-Hashem-nusach-Sephardi__p-12630.aspx

Comment: Great thank you very much!!